# ActiveMQ setup of tcp socket using mina

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel, apache-mina

I am trying to setup a simple demo of activemq and mina. I edited the camelContext in the activemq.xml file to include two mina tcp sockets, two queues and routes as such:

listenerA -> qA -> listenerB
listenerB -> qB -> listenerA

The intent is to have two way pass through between two telnet sessions. Later, I will add more fancy features such as filtering, routing to a topic and my own codec on each listener.

Here is my camelcontext:

```
    <!-- You can use a <package> element for each root package to search for Java routes --> 
    <package>com.myco.codec</package> 

    <endpoint id="listener_A" uri="mina:tcp://localhost:42000?textline=true"/> 
    <endpoint id="listener_B" uri="mina:tcp://localhost:42001?textline=true"/> 

            <!-- You can use Spring XML syntax to define the routes here using the <route> element --> 
    <route> 
        <from ref="listener_A"/> 
        <to uri="activemq:qA"/> 
    </route> 
    <route> 
        <from uri="activemq:qB"/> 
        <to ref="listener_A"/> 
    </route> 
    <route> 
        <from ref="listener_B"/> 
        <to uri="activemq:qB"/> 
    </route> 
    <route> 
        <from uri="activemq:qA"/> 
        <to ref="listener_B"/> 
    </route> 
</camelContext>
```

When I start activemq I get an exception:

org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: mina:tcp://localhost:42000?textline=true

Do I explicitly need to add a mina bean? If so where and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have camel-mina.jar and the mina jars on the classpath?

Based on [the thread here](http://www.nabble.com/Usage-of-Mina-in-camelContext-for-TCP-loop.-td20348095s22882.html) it seems to have fixed it.

Comment: The jar fixed it. (or rather brought me through to another problem).